# How to downgrade the .deb package to older version

Tags: debian, package-management, virtualbox

I have Oracle's Virtualbox repository configured. And today I did virtualbox-4.3 package upgrade to latest virtualbox-4.3 package. And it seems that I have problems with this package. So my question - is there any way to downgrade this package to my prevous .deb package? I can see that previous package is in local cache. I've tried to issue:

`apt-get install virtualbox-4.3=4.3_4.3.36-105129~Debian~squeeze`

but all I get is:

`E: Version '4.3_4.3.36-105129~Debian~squeeze' for 'virtualbox-4.3' was not found`

I suspect that there is no such package in Virtualbox repository anymore.

Comment: Point  a browser to the repository and see for yourself.

Comment: Ok, so how can I downgrade if the package is not in repository but if it is in my local cache?

Comment: sudo dpkg -i whatever.deb

Comment: Will I get the same effect as with apt-get install when the package is still in official repository?

Comment: Go ahead, try it, that´s what computers are for.

Comment: you may (probably will) have to install older versions of related packages.  I don't know how oracle package vbox, but the debian package Depends on `virtualbox-dkms` and Recommends `virtualbox-qt`.  just install them all on the same line with `dpkg -i`.   You can get info about a .deb package file, including dependencies etc, with `dpkg -I` (that's a capital `-I` for Info. lowercase `-i` is for install).  easier if you `cd /var/cache/apt/archives` first so you don't have to type or tab-complete the full path for multiple package files.

Comment: BTW, that's the reason apt exists - to automatically resolve dependencies, conflicts, etc when installing or upgrading packages.   downgrading a package is a mostly manual process, so you have to do most of that yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I've found the answer to my question. So The problem was how to install previous package when it was not able in repository anymore but was still available in local apt cache. So here is what I've did.

Created new folder /repo. Copied the required package into this folder. Went to this folder and issued the following command:

`dpkg-scanpackages -m . | gzip --fast > Packages.gz`

This command generated Packages.gz file with required content about my previous package. Then I've added local apt repository. How? Very simple. Created local.list file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and added following line into this file:

`deb file:/repo ./`

`apt-get update`

Thats it. Now I was able to install previous version of required package with the command:

`apt-get install virtualbox-4.3=4.3_4.3.36-105129~Debian~squeeze`

Comment: +1.  or you could do this instead of all the manual dependency resolution.  good answer.

Comment: Good answer indeed. Note that `apt` can take care of the dependencies for you, without needing a repository: change to the directory containing the package, and install it with `apt install ./package.deb` (the `./` is significant).